# Cannot find NodeJS in softwarecentre of Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs

I installed on an old pc Ubuntu desktop for testing Node.JS. According description in Desktop for developers:

> All the tools developers need
>   Whether your team uses Python, Ruby, Node.js or Java, no desktop operating system is easier to set up than Ubuntu.

But i just can´t find it in the softwarecenter? Searchinh this forum, i only found an answer for Ubuntu server?

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: I am totally new to ubuntu, where do i have to type those commands? (i stiil remember most dos-commands, but i am on my first hours with Ubuntu)

Comment: Open a terminal emulator window like gnome-terminal. You should find it in the Unity dash (button with Ubuntu symbol in the left bar on the top), look in the application lens (second item in the horizontal list at the bottom inside the dash) for it by either scrolling or type "terminal" into the search bar (top of the dash). You get a window that looks quite like a DOS prompt (username@pcname:directory$ ). You are in your user's home directory (~). Just type the commands here. I will copy them to a new answer that you have something to accept.

Comment: result: node -v
v0.10.36
The optional native addons went wrong, no acces to lock file, (13: acces denied), with remarks about having the right rights? Thanks for you answer anyways, tomorrow i will accept your answer, (much to late now for me, hours after midnight here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would open a terminal window (detailed instruction for bloody beginners in my comment above) and execute those two commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

<sub>Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager</sub>